# Android: ContextMenu and ItemSelected in Context Menu

Tags: android

This is the onCreate and oncontextitemslected code

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast toast;
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.context_menu_edit)
        {
            Log.d("ContextCheck","EDIT!");
            toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Edit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.context_menu_delete)
        {
            Log.d("ContextCheck","DELETE!");
            toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Delete!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

and before that is i used the method `registerForContextMenu(event_list)` where  `event_list` is a ListView , no i don't know why when ever i click an item from the context menu, it doesn't do anything, it won't show the toast and won't log into the logcat... is the item.getItemId() same for OptionsMenu and ContextManu?.. i don't know what is wrong with my code..

PS
the context menu is called inside a dialog box in a listview

Comment: Please check my edited answer. I made it working with a dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution, if you don't mind creating the menu items in your class. The keyword was definitely your PS, meaning your listview is in a dialog.

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
              super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
              //MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
              //inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

              MenuItem delete = menu.add("delete");
              MenuItem add = menu.add("add");
              add.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_upload); //adding icons
              delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                          Log.d("ContextCheck","EDIT!");
                            Toast.makeText(Pr.this, "Edit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              return true;
                      }
              });
              add.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                  public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                      Log.d("ContextCheck","EDIT!");
                        Toast.makeText(Pr.this, "Edit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      return true;
                  }
          });
            }
```

You do not even need the `onContextItemSelected` method.

Comment: yep yep it works fine!.. thank you very much!.. but one question why won't it work with the normal implementation of a context on dialog box on listview?...

Comment: I would say onContextItemSelected can be used for top-level classes, like an activity, and the dialog is a derived class. However according to the dev site, the package names are android.app.Activity and android.app.Dialog, so I don't know. Please delete your first comment, since it's irrelevant now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return true in the [onCreateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) as detailed in the documentation:

> **Returns**
>
> You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you
>   return false it will not be shown.

So you can chacnge your code to this:

```
@Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }
```

UPDATE:

I have things return on the options menu with a switch case in a `onOptionsItemSelected` vs `onContextItemSelected`

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.emaildev:    
                    email();
                    break;
                case R.id.share:     
                    Share();
                    break;                      
            }
            return true;
        }
```

The icons and ids are in my menu.xml

Comment: yep even though i didn't return true, i still got the options on the context menu, but i it won't do anything when i click the items in the context menu by the way how can u return somthing when its void?

Comment: yes but how are these gonna be implemented on ContextMenu, my options menu are working fine.. its just that on my ContextMenu, i don't do anything when i click an item on the contextmenu

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146909/oncontextitemselected-doesnt-get-called , Need to added an int arg to the onContextItemSelected method

Comment: I don't get it, why you say you need to return true inside a method that is declared as void ? That's not correct and nothing to do with the solution.